# What is the shear force at point B? Is it +P or -P or zero? I am not able to find any source that gives the right information

Tags: structural-engineering, strength, shear

[image]

I am not able to understand here that what should be the value of Shear force at point B. It seems to be a discontinous point, as there is point load there, but can we say about the exact value of shear force with sign?

Comment: There's a shear force of magnitude 2P applied at B. You don't show the original problem or a sign convention, so it can't be said what the force refers to or in what direction a load is acting.

Answer (score 1):

Shear is zero at where it crosses the reference axis. See the example below.

[image]